# Testing for accept button on winform application using CUI test builder

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I have a winforms application and I am writing some coded UI tests with basic assertions.  I am not sure how to confirm the accept button on a particular form.  When I create my assertion, I don't see a property to assert against.  I do see properties like enabled, exists, hasfocus when using the Coded UI test builder, but I don't see anything like "default button" or "accept button" either at the form level or the button level.

My question is particular to creating a Coded UI Test that can examine the form and verify the correct button is SET as the accept button. All code is generated by the Test Builder (in VS2012) and placed into a [classname].designer.cs file. There is no code to post since my question is around how to use the tool (or other means) to verify the forms Accept Button.

Comment: showing the code that you have tried so far and why it doesnt work would help this question.

Comment: @AbZy I do understand what the accept button, at the form level, means.  My question is particular to creating a Coded UI Test that can examine the form and verify the correct button is SET as the accept button.  All code is generated by the Test Builder (in VS2012) and placed into a [classname].designer.cs file.  There is no code to post since my question is around how to use the tool (or other means) to verify the forms Accept Button.

Comment: @JimKennedy I deleted the (possible duplicate) comment and vote. Please check out [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx#actions), it might be of help.

Comment: What do you want to do and what does "confirm the accept button" mean? Checking the presence of the button can be done by asserting on its name or displaytext or any of several other string properties. Checking for its presence and operation can be checked by clicking it (via `Mouse.Click(...)`).

Comment: @AdrianHHH, I appreciate the assistance from everyone, but the person who would eventually answer this will understand "confirm the accept button" probably because they have written numerous CUI tests.  And yes, you can assert on specific properties on any button on the form.  I do this all day.  However, I want to know that the correct button IS the accept button for the parent form.  I don't see a way to do this and Microsoft does not provide this through the builder tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up sending an [ENTER] key (rather than mouse.click) to the GUI in my script which will execute the accept button behavior (if one is assigned).  I can then assert on what follows after the Accept button click event fires.  It is an easy work around.  If for some reason there is a bug in the code and the wrong button click event fires, the assert will fail.

NOTE: In my application this is very important because my users are heavy keyboard users and the accept button is changed multiple times at runtime.  Confirming the correct behavior when the user strikes the [ENTER] key is very key to my app.

thanks